# How to structure ReactJS Component-Folder?

Tags: reactjs

Can we keep containers-folder outside of the components-folder ?.

And common-folder & helpers-folder inside component-folder ?

How can we arrange the below folders in components-folder ?

1. containers
2. pageContainers
3. common
4. utils
5. helpers

Comment: There is no "best way". Do whatever feels like the right way for your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my opinion the "modular" approach is a pretty good for react app. The purpose is to "scope" your files.
For example :

```
/src
 /Components
   /Button
     index.js
     style.css
 /Containers
   /Dashboard
     /Components
       ...somes components used only in dashboard
   index.js
   style.css
  /UserProfile
    /Components
     ...somes components used only in UserProfile
    /Service
      fetcher.js
      reducer.js
    index.js
    style.css
 /Services
   reducer.js
   /auth

     ...
 App.js
```

As you can see we have a "Container" folder  Each "module" has his own style, component, services, utils etc...

The benefits of "scoping" your application are:

- More easly maintenable
- The structure is more clear for the user, you don't have ton search your "Button component" in the only Component folder were you store 100 other components
- Evolutive. For exemple you have the "Auth module" wich allow the user to authenticate with your site. If you scope well your component it will be more easy to add some new ffeature for this service/component.

Of Course the general tree of folder will be bigger. You can adapt the structure with your needs but don't forget to think "scope".

This is probably not the "best way". but it has some very good advantages

if you want to go futher i recomand you the excellent article :https://medium.com/@alexmngn/why-react-developers-should-modularize-their-applications-d26d381854c1

and

https://medium.com/@alexmngn/how-to-better-organize-your-react-applications-2fd3ea1920f1

Comment: Where you keep your hooks?

Comment: For the store i generaly set a reducer per Container (or component if its needed) and export it. Then import it in my root reducer.
I don't use hooks in my apps for now so in can't tell !

Answer (score 1):

You can use **fractal file structure**, a comprehensive hackernoon post summarizes it all [here](https://hackernoon.com/fractal-a-react-app-structure-for-infinite-scale-4dab943092af).

It makes you reason about the location of files and folders, easier management of components, and paves way for infinite scaling.